# How to run a command n times in the fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish

The [fish documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/for.html) gives the following way to run a `for` loop.

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5;
    echo $i
end
```

Let us say I want to run a command 1000 times, How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same documentation, https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#loops-and-blocks :

```bash
for i in (seq 1 5)
    echo $i
end
```

replace `seq 1 5` with the numbers you want to get, e.g., `seq 14 1000` to get the numbers from 14 to 1000; if you want to start at 1, it's OK to omit the starting point, i.e., write `seq 1000`.

This, by the way, is like very classical UNIX shells; doesn't feel very modern. (In `bash` and `zsh` you can do `for i in {1..1000}`, which I consider easier and clearer to read, not to mention that it saves actually running an external program `seq` and buffering its output.)

Another way, which doesn't rely on coreutils (which is kind of a sad thing to rely on if you're not a GNU program nor a POSIX shell), would be using the `while` loop and purely fish builtin functions:

```bash
set counter 0
# -lt: less than
while test $counter -lt 1000;
    set counter (math $counter + 1)
    echo $counter
end
```

Comment: See also `repeat 1000 cmd` in `tcsh` or `zsh`. I guess, for simple commands, one could easily implement a function that does the same in `fish`.

Comment: In fish that could be `function repeat -a n; while test $n -gt 0; $argv[2..]; set n (math $n - 1); end; end` TODO add a guard to validate $n

Answer (score 5):

Turns out there is a program in the gnu-coreutils called `seq` which prints out a sequence of numbers.

So to run a command n times, the following loop can be used.

```
for i in (seq n);
    echo $i
end
```

Comment: this works for small n, as the shell needs to generate the sequence from 1...n before going through the for loop. Try the iterative method for less ram usage